# How would an OS in MIPS access peripherals?

Tags: assembly, kernel, mips

I've been reading about the MIPS assembly language for a while, just to learn. I get now that syscalls and exceptions in user code make the processor jump to a certain location in memory where the kernel and exception handled reside.

What I am curious about is how the OS can access peripherals, as I can't see any other relevant instructions. Does the processor export its own set of fundamental syscalls, or do the peripherals somehow get mapped to memory?

Comment: Yes you are right: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory-mapped_I/O

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MIPS does not have special IO instructions.  Peripherals are mapped to the flat physical address space via some memory bus interface and then accessed using standard load/store instructions.  MIPS does have coprocessor control instructions which could be used to manipulate some peripherals (primarily the MMU or cache controller), but these are not often used for general-purpose device interfaces.

Comment: Thanks for the help! One more thing, if you wouldn't mind - if a peripheral had some sort of interface that wasn't easily expressed as a block of memory, how would that be handled? Would the device's reference specify certain ranges of addresses to be written to to query the device, for example? I have the printed reference for the IBM PC with an Intel 8088, but it's instruction set has IO specific operations.

Comment: Memory mapped devices can do a lot of things that normal memory doesn't do.  Some memory addresses are device registers, used for controlling the device, others are for data passed to/from the device.  For example, a serial device might have a control register and a FIFO register.  Setting a bit in the control register enables the device, and repeatedly writing to the FIFO register outputs those bytes on the serial port.